# Authenticating a Java AWS SDK program for Hue on the Local Machine

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hue

I am trying to use a custom UDTF which pulls content from S3 into a table in Hue on my local machine.

I get the following error after running the `create temporary function` query:

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 
-101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.com/amazonaws/auth/
AWSCredentialsProvider
```

This is clearly due to my AWS Credentials not being picked up by Hue. The UDTF was created using the AWS Java SDK for Eclipse.

How does one go about authenticating Hue for use with AWS?

Comment: Hue is just a view on top of the CLI. How do you use your UDF with 'beeline'?